# Stanford CoreNLP python interface installation errors

Tags: python, java-native-interface, stanford-nlp, java

I'm trying to build the python interface of the stanford NLP on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.
There are two steps required, the first of which is:

1. compile Jpype by running "rake setup" in 3rdParty/jpype

When doing so I get the following error:

```
In file included from src/native/common/jp_monitor.cpp:17:0:
src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [cd JPype-0.5.4.1 && python setup.py build...]
```

The error messages says I'm missing `jni.h`, so as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250536/installing-stanford-parsers-python-interface-error-command-gcc-failed-with) if I ran the command `dpkg-query -L openjdk-7-jdk | grep "jni.h"` getting `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h`.

I believe that means I do have `jni.h` on my system, so I'm very confused right now. What is causing the error? Can you suggest any fix?

Thanks for your help!

---

**A FEW MORE INSIGHTS**

Here is the instruction causing the error:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08/include/linux -Isrc/native/common/include -Isrc/native/python/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/native/common/jp_class.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/native/common/jp_class.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from src/native/common/jp_class.cpp:17:0:src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It's coming from the compilation of `JPype` needed for the python interface. I do not know why but it includes paths that I don't have in my filesystem (i.e. `-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08/include/linux`).

How can I configure these paths correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a path problem (as said in the question and correctly answered by @vikramls).

Apparently when running the script for installing the python interface of the StanfordNLP if `JPype` is missing it will get installed with the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Now if you open the file `setup.py` you can see the following part which sets the `java` paths for a linux machine (I'm running on ubuntu):

```
def setupLinux(self):
    self.javaHome = os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
    if self.javaHome is None :
        self.javaHome = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08' # Ubuntu linux
        # self.javaHome = '/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_05'    
    self.jdkInclude = "linux"    
    self.libraries = ["dl"]
    self.libraryDir = [self.javaHome+"/lib"]
```

Clearly this path will not work on every machine, so there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Before running the installation script export a variable called `JAVA_HOME` with the location of your java installation. I.e. `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in my case.
2. As [this page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) says you can set an automatic include variable for `gcc` with the following command `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=some_path` and that path should be set to where you java libraries are on your machine

Answer (score 2):

The include paths specified do not include the path where jni.h is located.

From your grep, `jni.h` is located here: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h`

The include paths specified in the gcc args are: `-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.08/include/linux -Isrc/native/common/include -Isrc/native/python/include -I/usr/include/python2.7`

Sounds to me that you are building with the wrong java? You have a `java-1.5.0` install and a `java-7-openjdk` install - this one has the missing `jni.h` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That is exactly the problem, the only thing is that I had no idea on how to solve it ;) managed now though!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following question, it seems like you can fix this by setting `JAVA_HOME`.

[JPype compile problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649577/jpype-compile-problems)

So before building use:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Yup, I actually just figured that out on my own! lol, that's a weird way of using a bounty... ;D it got me more motivated to find the answer I guess!

Comment: I now get a similar error but this time with `Python.h` path: `src/native/python/include/jpype_python.h:24:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`. Since there is no variable in the `setup.py` that sets that do you have an idea of what I should do? Thanks

Comment: Verify you have the pyrhon-dev package. It might have a slightly different name on your distribution.